# Turning a multi-dictionary JSON into a Pandas dataframe

Tags: json, pandas, dataframe, api

I would like to turn a JSON data structure into a pandas dataframe. My data is retrieved from OpenWeatherMap. The resulting JSON contain multiple nested dictionaries which contain weather data on cities, divided by the URL where the data are retrieved from. Here the last two lines of the JSON, called json_data:

`http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?units=Imperial&APPID=a13759df887d2de294c2c7adef912758&q=new norfolk`:

```
{'coord': {'lon': 147.0587, 'lat': -42.7826}, 'weather': [{'id': 803, 'main': 'Clouds', 'description': 'broken clouds', 'icon': '04d'}], 'base': 'stations', 'main': {'temp': 46.04, 'feels_like': 44.29, 'temp_min': 43.92, 'temp_max': 51.93, 'pressure': 1000, 'humidity': 74}, 'visibility': 10000, 'wind': {'speed': 4, 'deg': 319, 'gust': 15.99}, 'clouds': {'all': 77}, 'dt': 1652657623, 'sys': {'type': 2, 'id': 2031307, 'country': 'AU', 'sunrise': 1652649449, 'sunset': 1652684337}, 'timezone': 36000, 'id': 2155415, 'name': 'New Norfolk', 'cod': 200}
```

`http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?units=Imperial&APPID=a13759df887d2de294c2c7adef912758&q=fortuna`:

```
{'coord': {'lon': -124.1573, 'lat': 40.5982}, 'weather': [{'id': 801, 'main': 'Clouds', 'description': 'few clouds', 'icon': '02d'}], 'base': 'stations', 'main': {'temp': 66.67, 'feels_like': 66.18, 'temp_min': 64.98, 'temp_max': 67.93, 'pressure': 1017, 'humidity': 67}, 'visibility': 10000, 'wind': {'speed': 17.27, 'deg': 360}, 'clouds': {'all': 20}, 'dt': 1652657623, 'sys': {'type': 2, 'id': 2040243, 'country': 'US', 'sunrise': 1652619589, 'sunset': 1652671580}, 'timezone': -25200, 'id': 5563839, 'name': 'Fortuna', 'cod': 200}
```

However, when I turn the JSON into a Pandas Dataframe, only the last dictionary goes into the dataframe.

Here is my code:

```
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.json_normalize(json_data)
```

Here is the result (I cannot copy the panda dataframe directly without losing formatting).

[image]

Why is only the last dictionary turned into a dataframe? How can I get a multiple-line dataframe?

Comment: What would your expected output be?

Answer (score 0):

If you're only seeing one line in your dataframe, you are probably overwriting your json_data with the last value.

Besides, you can normalize the weather column separately and join it to the rest:

```
json_data = [
    {'coord': {'lon': 147.0587, 'lat': -42.7826}, 'weather': [{'id': 803, 'main': 'Clouds', 'description': 'broken clouds', 'icon': '04d'}], 'base': 'stations', 'main': {'temp': 46.04, 'feels_like': 44.29, 'temp_min': 43.92, 'temp_max': 51.93, 'pressure': 1000, 'humidity': 74}, 'visibility': 10000, 'wind': {'speed': 4, 'deg': 319, 'gust': 15.99}, 'clouds': {'all': 77}, 'dt': 1652657623, 'sys': {'type': 2, 'id': 2031307, 'country': 'AU', 'sunrise': 1652649449, 'sunset': 1652684337}, 'timezone': 36000, 'id': 2155415, 'name': 'New Norfolk', 'cod': 200},
    {'coord': {'lon': -124.1573, 'lat': 40.5982}, 'weather': [{'id': 801, 'main': 'Clouds', 'description': 'few clouds', 'icon': '02d'}], 'base': 'stations', 'main': {'temp': 66.67, 'feels_like': 66.18, 'temp_min': 64.98, 'temp_max': 67.93, 'pressure': 1017, 'humidity': 67}, 'visibility': 10000, 'wind': {'speed': 17.27, 'deg': 360}, 'clouds': {'all': 20}, 'dt': 1652657623, 'sys': {'type': 2, 'id': 2040243, 'country': 'US', 'sunrise': 1652619589, 'sunset': 1652671580}, 'timezone': -25200, 'id': 5563839, 'name': 'Fortuna', 'cod': 200}
]

pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
df = pd.json_normalize(json_data)
df = df.loc[:, df.columns!='weather'].join(pd.json_normalize(json_data, record_path='weather', record_prefix='weather.'))

print(df)
```

Output:

```
       base  visibility          dt  timezone       id         name  cod  \
0  stations       10000  1652657623     36000  2155415  New Norfolk  200   
1  stations       10000  1652657623    -25200  5563839      Fortuna  200   

   coord.lon  coord.lat  main.temp  main.feels_like  main.temp_min  \
0   147.0587   -42.7826      46.04            44.29          43.92
1  -124.1573    40.5982      66.67            66.18          64.98

   main.temp_max  main.pressure  main.humidity  wind.speed  wind.deg  \
0          51.93           1000             74        4.00       319
1          67.93           1017             67       17.27       360

   wind.gust  clouds.all  sys.type   sys.id sys.country  sys.sunrise  \
0      15.99          77         2  2031307          AU   1652649449
1        NaN          20         2  2040243          US   1652619589

   sys.sunset  weather.id weather.main weather.description weather.icon
0  1652684337         803       Clouds       broken clouds          04d
1  1652671580         801       Clouds          few clouds          02d
```

As you can see, both lines are in the dataframe